# Error in replacing english numbers to arabic numbers using dictionary and linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I had written a function using dictionary and linq to replace English number to arabic number in any given string. But the function is not replacing exactly. For eg, if english number is 12345, the arabic number is 12534 or 53214 in arabic. What can be the problem?

My function is as follows,

```
private Dictionary<string, string> NumbersInArabic()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    dictionary.Add("0", "٠");
    dictionary.Add("1", "١");
    dictionary.Add("2", "٢");
    dictionary.Add("3", "٣");
    dictionary.Add("4", "٤");
    dictionary.Add("5", "٥");
    dictionary.Add("6", "٦");
    dictionary.Add("7", "٧");
    dictionary.Add("8", "٨");
    dictionary.Add("9", "٩");

    return dictionary;
}

private string ReplaceNumberTextToArabic(string text)
{
    var newstr = NumbersInArabic().Aggregate(text, (current, value) => current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));
    return newstr.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a problem with your dictionary? If you could change it to replacing digits with, say, English *letters* it would be easily for those of us who don't understand Arabic numbers to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written your method and it is working fine at my end.

I think your problem is some place else.

Comment: Which OS are you working on? It works fine in windows 7 and not in windows XP. Why?

Comment: I am using it as ReplaceNumberTextToArabic(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(lblRequestdate.Text)));

Comment: I am also using it as follows,

ReplaceNumberTextToArabic(string.Format("{0:N}", txtSalary12.Text))

Comment: it is replacing correctly but the arabic letters should be from right to left. How to do that?